# sbt 0.13.x migration to 1.1.4 with shell tasks

Tags: sbt, migration

I have a task to grab a frontend from git for my Play Framework application:

```
lazy val frontend = taskKey[Unit]("Downloads frontend")
frontend := {
  val s: TaskStreams = streams.value
  val shell: Seq[String] = if (sys.props("os.name").contains("Windows")) Seq("cmd", "/c") else Seq("bash", "-c")
  val downloadRepo: Seq[String] = shell :+ "git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/frontend.git"
  val rmJs: Seq[String] = shell :+    "rm -rf frontend/dist/js && rm -rf public/design && mkdir public/design"
  val copy: Seq[String] = shell :+    "mv frontend/dist/* public/design/"
  val rmRepo: Seq[String] = shell :+    "rm -rf frontend"
  s.log.info("Downloading frontend...")
  if((downloadRepo #&& rmJs #&& copy #&& rmRepo !) == 0) {
    s.log.success("frontend downloaded successful!")
  } else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("frontend failed!")
  }
}
```

and it works fine with sbt 0.13.x, but I want to migrate to newest one and it gives me an error:

```
error: value #&& is not a member of Seq[String]
  if((downloadRepo #&& rmJs #&& copy #&& rmRepo !) == 0) {
```

I checked new documentation and didn't find an answer, how can I migrate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean the [`#&&`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html#&&(other:scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder):scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder) operator from `sys.process`:

> `#&&` conditionally executes the second command if the previous one finished with exit value 0. It mirrors shell's `&&`.

sbt 0.13 had an API similar to that of `sys.process` and in 1.0 `sys.process` replaced it. So the fix would be just to import it to add relevant implicints to the scope:

```
import scala.sys.process._
```